# Data from 2 eyes and repeated measures across time

Tags: r, mixed-model, repeated-measures

I have data from two eyes that have been repeatedly measured across time (5 time points) for their intraocular pressure (IOP). Various measurements were taken including categorical and continuous data. Not all patients have both eyes eligible for the study, so there is a mixture of patients, some with 1 and some with 2 eyes. Covariates assesed at baseline include age, gender, corneal thickness and other parameters that vary between eyes of each participant.

I have formatted the data so that there are additional rows for each eye and rows for each measurement across time. I also want to investigate the interaction effect between CornealThickness and Time, as well as Gender and Time.

Is the following the correct specification of the model in R, specifically  unsure how nesting should be specified:

`lmer(IOP ~ Age + Gender + CornealThickness + as.factor(Time) + Gender*as.factor(Time) + CornealThickness*as.factor(Time) + (1|ID/Eye), data=data)`

Alternatively, would it be the following:

`lmer(IOP ~ Age + Gender + CornealThickness + as.factor(Time) + Gender*as.factor(Time) + CornealThickness*as.factor(Time) + (as.factor(Time)|ID/Eye), data=data)`

UPDATE: I have tried to run the mmrm model on this dataset:

```
 m1 <-  mmrm::mmrm( formula = IOP ~ age + eye_visit +diabetes_duration+ us(eye_visit | id), data = data, control = mmrm_control(method = "Kenward-Roger") )
```

However I get the following error message:

> Problem with these data entries: y_vector
> 5  Error in fit_single_optimizer(formula = formula, data = data, weights = weights,  :    Only numeric matrices, vectors, arrays,
> factors, lists or length-1-characters can be interfaced

What does this mean?

Thank you!

Comment: Is there some reason why you are treating `Time` as a factor instead of continuous?

Comment: Longitudinal data are often best handled using [serial correlation models and not random effects](https://fharrell.com/post/re) so here you have an ideal case for having random effects for patients (assuming exchangeability of eyes) and a serial correlation structure for the longitudinal part, e.g., generalized least squares or a Markov model.  A Bayesian random effects Markov model would be especially of interested.  See [here](https://hbiostat.org/rmsc/markov).

Comment: @FrankHarrell, doesn't the second model also allow for (unstructured) correlation over time? At least, given the choice between these two, I would certainly prefer the latter. The nesting hierarchy should not matter because each subject should only have one of each eye (per timepoint), so the choice is between 2 N*N blocks or N 2*2 blocks.

Comment: I missed that there is only one eye studied per person.  Then I would go with generalized least squares or a Markov model and not use random effects.  If time is discrete (unlikely) and there are < 4 distinct measurement times then an unstructured covariance matrix can work well.

Comment: @FrankHarrell , Some participants may have 2 eyes studied, depending on eligibility of the eye. So we have at most 2 eyes measured per person over 5 time points.

Comment: @EdM, it was specified as discrete to obtain the effect of corneal thickness at each time-point

Comment: I don’t understand what that has to do with it being discrete.  Continuous-time models allow estimation at all possible times.

Comment: @FrankHarrell , Sure, I will need to check the correct functional form for time , and then specify it as continuous in the model with the correct transformation if non-linear.

Comment: Would the autoregressive correlation structure be better in this case, if modelled using a linear mixed effects model. I'm not too familiar with generalised least squares or markov models so it was not my go to model, but thanks very much for the references which I shall go over. I was really just wondering how this case may be modelled using a linear mixed effects model, when you have time nested within eye nested within person.

Comment: Is it possible to model two levels of correlation, 1) autoregressive for measurments between time points and 2) exchangeable or unstructured for measurements between eyes?

Comment: Yes, in several mixed model packages you can specify a correlation structure that is added on top of the structure induced by random intercepts or slopes.

Comment: @PBulls Thanks very much for the response. May I ask why the nesting hierarchy doesn't matter in this case? In that case would neither of the models I proposed specify the structure in my data

Comment: The nesting would matter if you also want to specify an effect across subjects (not eyes) or eyes (not subjects), but you only have the single random effect within both subjects and eyes, and since each subject has only one eye of each it doesn't matter what order you put them in.

Comment: @PBulls Thanks very much! Since there is just single random effect for ID, does this mean that the model should be specified as follows: lmer(IOP ~ ....+ time ....+ (1|ID), data=data) ? Not all patients have 2 eyes eligible, would this be a major cause for concern, or does the model allow for this?

Comment: Correlation structures like autoregressive, especially AR(1) over time tend to be terrible in terms of how they behave. They usually overestimate correlation of near-by observation and then - usually wrongly decide that observations that are sufficiently far apart are totally independent (when the data usually clearly contradicts that).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Another approach you can take is to look at observations from separate eyes as if they were at different times and let the data largely determine the appropriate correlations (and levels of variability) between observations from the two eyes. E.g. using the `mmrm` R package (assuming everything you want to be a factor is already a factor, and where `eye_visit` is a factor that's a concatenation of `eye` and `visit`, such as `"left_week4"`, `"right_week4"`, `"left_week8"` etc.):

```
mmrm::mmrm(
  formula = IOP ~ 0 + eye_visit + ...other model terms... + us(eye_visit | id),
  data = data,
  control = mmrm_control(method = "Kenward-Roger")
)
```

(see here for an [introduction to the package](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/mmrm/vignettes/introduction.html)).

The advantages of this approach include that

1. you don't assume the variability at each visit/for each eye is the same over time (often variability goes up over time), and
2. you flexibly estimate how correlated different timepoints (and the eyes in the same person) are from the data without imposing something like a AR(1) structure (that tends to be very wrong for any real data, but if you assumed a more structured covariance structure that is appropriate you might have a gain in efficiency).

Additionally, you can think about what variables should have an interaction with time and/or eye (e.g. a baseline starting assessment would usually be allowed to interact with the factor for time). However, that's possible in any of the models that were already mentioned.

Example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mmrm)

set.seed(42)
example <- tibble(eye=rep(c("left", "right"), 30),
                  visit=rep(rep(c("Week0", "Week4", "Week8"), each=2), 10),
                  id=rep(1L:10L, each=6),
                  random_subject_effect = rnorm(n=10, mean=0, sd=10)[id],
                  age = sample(18:85, size=10, replace=T)[id],
                  IOP = rnorm(n=60, 
                              mean=random_subject_effect+10-(eye=="left")*3+as.integer(str_extract(visit, "[0-8]+")), 
                              sd=5)) %>%
  dplyr::select(-random_subject_effect) %>%
  mutate(eye_visit = factor(paste0(eye, "_", visit)),
         id=factor(id))

mmrmfit1 <- mmrm::mmrm(
  formula = IOP ~ 0 + eye_visit + age + us(eye_visit | id),
  data = example,
  method = "Kenward-Roger")

mmrmfit1 %>%
  summary()
```

Comment: I tried to run the model however I am getting the following error message: "Problem with these data entries:
y_vector 
       5 
Error in fit_single_optimizer(formula = formula, data = data, weights = weights,  : 
  Only numeric matrices, vectors, arrays, factors, lists or length-1-characters can be interfaced". I have added this as an update to the question. Thanks!

Comment: I've added an example, which runs fine for me. I'm not 100% sure what triggers that error message you show, but have you checked 1) that the input you provide is a data.frame or tibble, (2) that the key variables you need to be factors are factors (e.g. `id` and `eye_visit`), (3) that there's nothing funny about other columns (e.g. `IOP`, `age` and `diabetes_duration` should be numeric columns and not have anything like, say, list entries)?

Comment: Thanks very much for the example, it was very helpful! Setting eye_visit and id to factors didn't work. But my dependent variable was actually a labelled numeric, after setting this to numeric, the code ran!

Comment: Also, why add the "0" to the formula ? Thanks

Comment: It doesn't really matter either way when you fit a model using some form of maximum likelihood, the inference is just the same if you have an intercept or not (as long as you form your contrasts appropriately from the fit model using e.g. `emmeans::emmeans()`). `1+eye_visit` (same as `eye_visit`) makes the `eye_visit` coefficients refer to how much any eye-visit combination deviates from the intercept (which refers to the reference category), while `0+eye_visit` omits the intercept so that each is kind of the absolute level for each eye-visit (kind of, bc there's of course other covariates).

Comment: Thank you very much! I was just reading more into mmrm models and understand that they are a special case of mixed effects models where the unstructured covariance structure is used. What are the model assumptions that apply ? Is normality of the residuals a key modelling assumption and are there any packages that can model the residual diagnostics? Thanks!

Comment: Multivariate normality of residuals would indeed be one assumption. Of course, some degree of deviation would be as usual probably rather unproblematic.

Comment: Thank you. I just had a question about if we were having mean change values as the outcome, rather than absolute values of IOP. Is it ok to regress mean change in IOP from baseline to each time point as the outcome, then adjust for baseline IOP in the predictors in this type of model? Wouldn't this mean we have baseline in the outcome as well as in the predictors? Is this a problem?

Comment: It's usually more or less the same thing. E.g. if in a RCT you adjust for baseline (and have baseline by visit interactions), then for estimating treatment differences, you end up with the same results whether you analyse absolute values or change from baseline.

Comment: Thanks. I was able to estimate the adjusted mean absolute value of IOP at each time point using emmeans(m1, ~time) where m1 is the mmrm object fit. But how does one get the adjusted mean change values at each time point from this model? Is this when you would have the mean change as the outcome, rather than absolute values? Thank you!

Answer (score 5):

> Is the following the correct specification of the model in R, specifically unsure how nesting should be specified:

> ```
> lmer(IOP ~ Age + Gender + CornealThickness + as.factor(Time) + Gender*as.factor(Time) + CornealThickness*as.factor(Time) + (1|ID/Eye), data=data)
> ```

> Alternatively, would it be the following:

> ```
> lmer(IOP ~ Age + Gender + CornealThickness + as.factor(Time) + Gender*as.factor(Time) + CornealThickness*as.factor(Time) + (as.factor(Time)|ID/Eye), data=data)
> ```

The only difference between these models is that in the latter one, random slopes for each time point are specified.

Either model could be appropriate, but consider these issues:

- Serial correlation of residuals within subjects. The model fitted by `lmer`  assumes that residuals are independent and identically distributed. However, as mentioned by Frank Harrell in the question comments, this type of study (longitudinal) should be expected to involve serial correlation. That is, the residuals are expected to feature a serial correlation structure in which the correlation between two measurements on the same subject decreases as the time gap widens. The `lmer` function cannot handle this so if would be a good idea to consider using `nlme` instead which does offer various correlation structures such as AR(1). Alternatively, again as mentioned by Frank Harrell, a Discrete Time Markov Model or a Generalised Least Squares model should be considered. [See here](https://hbiostat.org/proj/covid19/ordmarkov.html) for an excellent introduction to Markov Models for longitudinal data.
- The presence of random slopes in the second model is reasonable if we expect that the effect of each `Time` point to vary by subject, though be aware that this sometimes causes a difficulty in fitting leading to a singular model.
- Nesting structure: `|ID/Eye` says that Eye is nested within ID, which appears to be correct. @PBulls makes an interesting point about not needing the random intercepts for `Eye`, however I'm not sure that I fully agree. I would suggest fitting the nested model and a simpler model with random intercepts for just `ID` and compare the results.